# In SQLite is there a way to test if two tables are identical?

Tags: sqlite

Assume the two tables reside in the same file. So the question is, other than their names, are the tables identical, i.e., same schema, same contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the table schemas, look at the statements in the [sqlite_master table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master):

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name IN ('This', 'That');
```

You have to ignore the table name itself in the comparison; automatic replacement is harder if you have any column names or comments that containt the table name.

To compare the contents, just use [compound queries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to check whether there are any rows that are not in the other table:

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM This
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT * FROM That)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM That
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT * FROM This);
```

Comment: I tested your solution on two tables I know to be equal and it returned 1. I agree that, for the sake of efficiency, it's probably better to first compare schemas and row counts. My tables have about 1.5M rows and 205 columns and the select statement shown above took a few minutes to execute. I'm not sure how one would compare the schemas in SQL as they must contain different table names. Perhaps you mean that you'd import the result into a programming environment and compare them there?

Comment: That would be the usual implication on this site. ;-) Anyway, you could just do a `replace()` on the `sql` values, and then compare them (e.g. GROUP BY).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following may suffice :-

```
/*
   Compare Schema and data in tables.
     
     t1 is the SQL for the first table (mytable) with the table name changed to a common name (table)
     t2 is the SQL for the second table (mytable_copy1) with the table changed to a common name (table)
     (so if t1 and t2 are equal then the schema is the same)
     
     tablecompare is the logical result of comparing the data of each table with the other table
     except matching rows so if no rows exists then NOT EXISTS will be true (1) AND the two
     and the result will be 1 if both tables exactly match each other.
 
*/

SELECT 
    (t1 = t1) AND tablecompare  AS test FROM 
            (SELECT 
                replace(sql,'mytable','table') AS t1, -- change the table name to a common name
                replace(sql,'mytable_copy1','table') AS t2, -- change the table name to a common name
                
                (
                    SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable EXCEPT SELECT * FROM mytable_copy1) 
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable_copy1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM mytable) 
                ) AS tablecompare
                FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'mytable'
)
```

- Note the tables are mytable and mytable_copy1 so these would be changed to reflect the two tables.

Perhaps less confusing (perhaps more) is this more long-winded solution :-

```
/*

   Table Compare
     
     t1 is the SQL for the first table (mytable) with the table name replace by table
     t2 is the SQL for the second table (mytable_copy1) again table name change to table
     So if t1 = t2 then the schema is identical
     
     t1count is the number of rows in the first table 
     t2count is the number of rows in the second table
     So if the counts are the same then the tables may be identical
     
     unioncount is the count of the union of the two tables (not union all) so duiplicates are dropped
     therefore if unioncount is the same as either of the table counts then tables are identical
     NOTE!!! this assumes tables are not WITHOUT ROWID tables (would have to omit the inclusion of rowid NOT TESTED)
     the inclusion of rowid could be dropped (NOT TESTED) if there is an alias of rowid.
*/
SELECT 
    t1 = t1 AND t1count = t2count AND t1count = unioncount AS test FROM 
            (SELECT 
                replace(sql,'mytable','table') AS t1, -- change the table name to a common name
                replace(sql,'mytable_copy1','table') AS t2, -- change the table name to a common name
        
                (SELECT count() FROM mytable) AS t1count, -- get the number of rows
                (SELECT count() FROM mytable_copy1) AS t2count, -- get the number of rows
                (SELECT count() AS unioncount FROM
            (SELECT rowid,* FROM mytable UNION SELECT rowid,* FROM mytable_copy1)) AS unioncount
                FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'mytable'
) ;
```

**Both solutions return a single row/column result 1 if the tables match 0 if they do not.**

It could however, but less time consuming/resource hungry to do individual tests. e.g. if the schema's don't match do nothing otherwise check the row counts and if they don't match don't do the final check of actually checking the data.

### Test the following tables were used for testing :-

For mytable and mytable_copy1 :-

[image]

The above both produced 1 as per :-

[image]

and :-

[image]

When the following table (mytable_copy2 with changed data highlighted) :-

[image]

The results were :-

[image]

and :-

[image]